# nslcd with domain.com and sub.domain.com

Tags: linux, active-directory, authentication, pam-ldap

i'm trying to setup our linux server with nslcd within multiple AD Domains, example.com and sub.exmaple.com.

The current setup with nslcd is pretty easy and works for the domain example.com:

```
uid nslcd
gid ldap

uri ldaps://dc1.example.com:636

base dc=example,dc=com

binddn cn=srv_authuser,ou=server,dc=example,dc=com
bindpw ----
tls_reqcert never

pagesize 1000
referrals off
idle_timelimit 800
filter passwd (&(objectClass=user)(!(objectClass=computer)))
map    passwd uid              sAMAccountName
map    passwd uidNumber        objectSid:S-1-5-21-4129304498-564803152-741489137
map    passwd gidNumber        gidNumber
map    passwd loginShell       "/bin/bash"
map    passwd homeDirectory    "/home/$sAMAccountName"
map    passwd gecos            displayName)(!(objectClass=computer))(uidNumber=*)(unixHomeDirectory=*))
map    group  gidNumber        objectSid:S-1-5-21-4129304498-564803152-741489137
map    shadow uid              sAMAccountName
map    shadow shadowLastChange pwdLastSet
filter group  (objectClass=group)

tls_cacertdir /etc/openldap/cacerts
ssl on
```

Is it possible with nslcd (pam-nss-ldap) to set up an second ldap query for sub.domain.com or is this only possible via sssd?
If the bind user has admin rights on sub.domain.com, could he fetch also passwords/account data?

Thanks

Comment: Please let me know if the solution I purposed below worked fine for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do what you want with just nslcd. Instead you will have to configure  a fake LDAP server with the fake domain name served by slapd with slapd-meta or slapd-ldap backend. Then you will add your AD servers to e.g. fakedomain.local. Once it's done you will be able to enroll your client to the fakedomain.local that will have a few domains inside. Then you will be able to list users from two different LDAP servers.

here is a sample of your LDAP proxy configuration:

sudo yum install -y openldap openldap-clients openldap-servers

cat /etc/openldap/slapd.conf

```
include /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/corba.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/duaconf.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/dyngroup.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/java.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/openldap.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/collective.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/pmi.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema

allow bind_v2
allow bind_anon_cred
pidfile         /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile        /var/run/openldap/slapd.args
modulepath      /usr/lib64/openldap/
moduleload      rwm.la
moduleload      back_ldap.la
moduleload      back_meta.la
loglevel        4095

attributetype ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.656 NAME 'userPrincipalName' EQUALITY caseExactMatch SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15' SINGLE-VALUE )

#Active Directory1
database        meta
suffix          "dc=fakedomain,dc=local"
uri             "ldap://ipofyourldap1:389/dc=fakedomain,dc=local"
readonly        yes
lastmod         off
suffixmassage   "dc=fakedomain,dc=local" "ou=users,ou=office,dc=real1,dc=domain"
idassert-bind bindmethod=simple
   binddn="CN=userwithadminrights,OU=users,OU=office,DC=real1,DC=domain"
   credentials="yourplaintextpassword"
idassert-authzFrom "*"

#Active Directory2
database        meta
suffix          "dc=fakedomain,dc=local"
uri             "ldap://ipofyourldap2:389/dc=fakedomain,dc=local"
readonly        yes
lastmod         off
suffixmassage   "dc=fakedomain,dc=local" "ou=users,ou=office,dc=real2,dc=domain"
idassert-bind bindmethod=simple
   binddn="CN=userwithadminrights,OU=users,OU=office,DC=real2,DC=domain"
   credentials="yourplaintextpassword"
idassert-authzFrom "*"
```

Add the following:

```
#####################ADD TO /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema############
attributetype ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.221
      NAME 'sAMAccountName'
            SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15' SINGLE-VALUE )

#####################ADD TO /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema############
```

sudo rm -r /etc/openldap/slapd.d && sudo mkdir /etc/openldap/slapd.d && sudo chown -R ldap.ldap /etc/openldap/slapd.d

sudo slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d

sudo slapd -d 1

Comment: I am glad it worked for you!